# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS from USB on an UEFI system stops in grub rescue shell - how to continue?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi, hp

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 from USB on a system with UEFI (from HP) instead of BIOS where Windows 7 is preinstalled.

Unfortunately booting from USB-Stick hangs at the Grub "rescue shell" with the following behavior:

- the prompt is visible and keyboard input is possible
- the visible screen shows only half of what grub things that the screen is big
- the `clear` command only makes the prompt restart from the top of the screen but does not clear anything

I have disabled "secure boot" in UEFI, actually it was disabled from the start.

How can I start the ubuntu installer from the rescue shell?

Why didn't it start on its own? (I have installed many Ubuntu's, also one 14.04, and never saw such a problem)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to boot the USB by doing the following:

- enter commands in grub shell

  ```
  insmod linux
  linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper
  initrd /casper/initrd.lz
  boot
  ```
- double click the "Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS" icon on the desktop

Now my original question is solved, I am in the installer interface.

(However now I have a second problem: no partitions are displayed for installing Linux. The Windows drive seems to have no partitions.)

Comment: I think in the end I disabled UEFI completely and configured the BIOS to use legacy booting.